# Correct word to use for graduation

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning

Is it correct to use the following sentence - 'I passed out of University in 2010' 
What could be more appropriate or better way to say it

Comment: What's wrong with _graduated? Pass out_  is usually used with reference to military training.

Comment: Technically a person may pass but not graduate. I passed a B.Sc. but did not graduate with that degree. I graduated with B.Sc.(hons) a year later.

Comment: Do you mean complete university ("graduated"/"graduated from"), or stop attending before completion ("dropped out of")?

Answer (score 1):

"Passed out of university" isn't correct. You might say any of these instead:

- I finished University in 2010
- I graduated from University in 2010
- I completed my University degree in 2010
- I achieved my degree in 2010 (this one is more formal)
- I left University in 2010 (this could mean you graduated or that you just stopped attending)
- I attended University until 2010.

#### Note About Dialects

In the US specifically, "University" is not a commonly used word by itself. You might say "My university" or "University of California" or "the university I attended" but not just "I went to university."

If you are talking about a Bachelor's degree, you'd usually say "College" instead. If you're talking about a Master's Degree or a Ph.D., you'd say "grad school" and if you're talking about a different degree, you'd refer to it by name (mostly, there are a few exceptions).